# WPF downloaded images don't seem to work

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, download

This is a bit of an odd one... Certain images... Not sure what differentiates them yet (all .jpg files) don't seem to work in WPF... Until I open them in paint and resave (even without making any changes. Although I realise that resaving a jpg always changes it.)

A really simple XAML file with

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\ChromeTest.jpg" />
```

doesn't work (error message "Value does not fall within the expected range") on the file downloaded through chrome or IE... But works just fine on the file if I resave it... Am I missing something obvious here?

(I also tried a few of the .NET methods and they all seem to come out with the same issue, one way or another.)

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty obvious question is: are you sure that images are well formed? Paint may be more tolerant about ill files than decoder used by WPF (assuming it's not some strange behavior of the protection for downloaded files imposed by Windows).

Comment: You might want to `Unblock` the file after downloading and before using it. Open file properties dialog box for that file and try Unblocking it. Refer to this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eniqF.png)

Comment: @Chris - Can you post the file URL here from where you downloaded the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but got this link [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DealingWithImagesWithBadMetadataCorruptedColorProfilesInWPF.aspx) which talks about bad jpg files with corrupt data (`corrupt color profile`).

It provides a workaround as well that setting `CreateOptions` to `IgnoreColorProfile` on image will work for those corrupt images.

Try this for your image as well and see if problem gets resolved with that -

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
     <BitmapImage CreateOptions="IgnoreColorProfile" 
                  UriSource="C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\ChromeTest.jpg"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Very good spot! Pretty handy that you came down to exactly the problem I was suffering from. This also enabled me to load the image in the CodeBehind just fine, so this is the problem I had, most certainly.